# PHP get an object from inside a callback

Tags: php, object, callback

I want to get an errors object from a callback function. here is what i have done so far.

```
$errors = null;

set_exception_handler(function($exception) use (&$errors) {
  $errors = $exception;

   var_dump($exception); // works fine      

});

var_dump($errors); // give null ???? 


throw new Exception("blablblablablabla", 0);
```

I am sure with an anonymous function and a variable would work very fine ! 
 But in this case with a callback and object I am not sure what's going on ? i can't get my head a round. any help explanation would be really appreciated.

Comment: Looks like there is nor error before `var_dump($errors);` `var_dump($exception);` is in the callback.

Comment: @Peter just throw an exception at the bottom of the script and the exception handler will catch it :p

Comment: At `var_dump($errors)`, `$errors` is still set to `null`. Why wouldn't it be? The exception hasn't been thrown yet.

Comment: try to throw the exception before `var_dump($errors);`

Comment: @Don'tPanic so you mean that there is a kind of stopping of execution by the end of the exception handler ?

Comment: @LotfioLakehal Quote from the [`set_exception_handler` manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-exception-handler.php): *Execution will stop after the exception_handler is called.*

Comment: Yes indeed. See the above quote from the `set_exception_handler` manual.

Comment: @PhilippMaurer I am not sure at which level it stops the execution. but if you try to execute something after `set_exception_handler` its works very fine :p

Comment: @LotfioLakehal It does not mean that the execution will stop after `set_exception_handler()` is called, but that it will stop after the handler (our anonymous function) is called. Therefore, even tough `$errors` is overwritten, no code will run to prove that out of the scope of your function.

Comment: Thanks @PhilippMaurer . i got the point . appreciate it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`set_exception_handler` does not stop execution. It just defines what will happen if/when an exception occurs, so you can `var_dump($errors);` errors after setting it. `$errors` will still be null at that point because you have set it to null, and nothing has happened yet to change that.

The thing that *does* stop execution is when an exception actually occurs and the anonymous function defined in `set_exception_handler` is called. At that point, the `var_dump($exception);` within that function is called, but any other code in the main program after the point where the exception occurred will not be executed.

Storing the exception in a global variable from within the exception handler doesn't make really sense, because if the exception handler is called, no more code in the main program will be executed, so you won't be able to use that variable anyway.

Answer (score 1):

You are assigning the anonymous function as an exception handler with [`set_exception_handler()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-exception-handler.php).

Yet you do not throw an exception in your code. Therefore the anonymous function is never called, because there was no event to handle, which means that `$error` was never set.

If you add a `try catch` block your function will also not be called. This can be seen by the fact, that the line `var_dump($exception)` from within your handler is not called either.

If you want to store the last called exception in your code, you may need to use a wrapper function around that code, that uses `try catch` to overwrite a static resource with the last exception encountered.

**Note, that the exception within the given function is never fully thrown, because it was catched by the wrapper!**

```
class Catcher {
    private static $_EXCEPTION = null;

    public static function GET_EXCEPTION () {
        return self::$_EXCEPTION;
    }

    public static function run($func) {
        try {
            return $func();
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            self::$_EXCEPTION = $e;
        }
    }
}

var_dump(Catcher::GET_EXCEPTION()); //dumps NULL

Catcher::run(function(){
    throw new Exception('I was called');
});


var_dump(Catcher::GET_EXCEPTION()); //dumps the last thrown exception
```

Comment: nope I have already thrown exceptions and tested it ! you can just try it and see. the exception will be caught withing the callback but cant be stored in an external variable.

Comment: @LotfioLakehal Hey, i overworked my answer to provide a possible solution to your static exception storage and modified the `try catch` exception handler part.

Comment: The solution would require to wrap the whole code inside an `Catcher::run()` wrapper and is therefore not suitable for existing / large / framework projects.

Comment: but like that you are not controlling the default exception handler ! you are just making a wrapper to to your exceptions ?

Comment: @LotfioLakehal Yes